# Trying to set up a home webserver using Ubuntu and Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, router, apache-http-server, firewall

The steps I’ve taken:

- Installed Ubuntu on old laptop.
- Given the laptop a static IP address in local network of `10.1.1.12`.
- Add a service to [Netgear DG834GU](http://kbserver.netgear.com/pdf/dg834_g_b_manual_v2.pdf) router for port 80 TCP/UDP
- Set up a firewall rule in Netgear for port 80 that allows any WAN user and logs always sending to `10.1.1.12`.

I can get to `10.1.1.12` on local network and see webpages ok. When I try to view from external network (my phone, for example) using my ISP assigned IP address, I get a:

> Read Error: The system returned (104) Connection reset by peer.

When I go to `canyouseeme.org` it says:

> Error: I could not see your service on 114.xxx.xx.13 on port (80)
>   Reason: Connection refused

I went to my ISP toolbox and port 80 is not blocked there.

If I try to use xampp or any other little webserver on my Windows 7 machine the same thing happens. I tried disabling windows firewall and nothing changed.

From the tutorials I read I don’t have to do anything further with Apache. I removed and purged and reinstalled it just in case I had stuffed it up somehow. Now it's pretty much as-new.

Could this be happening because my connection is too slow or could it possibly be another problem? The server has a timeout of 300 seconds but I noticed when I try to access it it stops trying after 15-20. How would I determine exactly what the problem is? Is there a tool that anyone knows of that would be able to tell me?

Here are [images of the router setup screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtauU.png).

Just looked at the router logs again:

```
Firewall: packet accept. 49.183.xx.xx(44947) --> 114.xxx.xx.xx(80),
Protocol TCP. Tuesday, Feb 10,2015 01:56:54 Firewall: packet accept.
49.183.xx.xx(44947) --> 114.xxx.xx.xx(80), Protocol TCP. Tuesday, Feb 10,2015 01:56:44 Firewall: packet accept. 49.183.xx.xx(44946) -->
114.xxx.xx.xx(80), Protocol TCP. Tuesday, Feb 10,2015 01:55:02 Firewall: packet accept. 49.183.xx.xx(44946) --> 114.xxx.xx.xx(80),
Protocol TCP. Tuesday, Feb 10,2015 01:54:52
```

So something is happening… But still no serving of the webpages externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to look for a "DMZ" option in your router settings.

When I set up my web server I had to go to 192.168.0.1 to access my router (that may be different for you) and then navigate around until I found "DMZ HOST"... change that to your *local* I.P. for your *web server*.  That was a problem I had.  Hope that helps.

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:
[my /etc/network/interfaces file](http://www.encyclotron.com/example) and works fine.

Comment: I've set up the webserver IP as DMZ server but it's not working. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Okay it's working YAY!, not sure why but it must have taken some time to start working. Thanks again I really appreciate it. You're a superstar!

Answer (score 0):

You can try experimenting with a service such a cloudflare.com to connect your domain name with your servers external ip address. The problem may be that you have a dynamic ip address that changes frequently, you can also look into a service at http://dyn.com/... or look into getting a cloud service somewhere and install ubuntu+apache using sftp to upload your content to /var/www/html.

Comment: I have connected my domain name with my IP using the namesevers of my domain registrar. It's just not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall service, such as [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), running on the Ubuntu system? If so, is it configured to allow port 80 connections from all external addresses rather than just from other computers on your LAN?

On Linux systems, you can use [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump), which is a [packet analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer), aka "sniffer", for troubleshooting such problems. By running it on your webserver, you will be able to see whether the TCP packets are reaching the server. A comparable program for Windows systems, which you could run on the Windows 7 system, if you configured it as a webserver, is [WinDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/). Those are command line utilities. For a graphical user interface (GUI), you could use [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).

For information on how to use tcpdump (WinDump uses a similar syntax), see [Capturing Packets with Tcpdump](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/capturing-packets-with-tcpdump).

Another place to check is Apache's logs to see if they are showing any connections from external systems. You should be able to find the locations for the Apache logs from the Apache httpd.conf file.