# Accessing Apache on network Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a ubuntu installation running on my network and I can access the SSH using the IP from my windows machine. Apache is installed on the ubuntu box and I can access apache from within the ubuntu using 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'

I can also connect to my ubuntu box from Windows using putty and Xshell. The problem is that I can't access the apache on ubuntu from my windows machine ( windows 7)

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)



vivek@frankgd-DX4860:~$ sudo ufw status
WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache', using last found
WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache Secure', using last found
WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache Full', using last found
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

vivek@frankgd-DX4860:~$
```

Comment: how are you trying to access it?

Comment: Are you trying to access it through your local network?  Or are you looking to get to it from wherever?  You may want to take a look at this other question as one of the answers seems to have worked [This might help] (http://superuser.com/questions/876383/trying-to-set-up-a-home-webserver-using-ubuntu-and-apache2/876390#876390)

Comment: It seems that you try to access ssh server using windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall settings seem ok but to make sure, check iptables directly:

```
iptables -L
```

Another possibility is that Apache isn't listening on your "external" IP Address. Check your `Listen` directive. If it's set to localhost or 127.0.0.1, you've found it. In that case, simply set it to the port and it'll bind to all available addresses:

```
Listen 80
```