# raspberry pi ip address and port forwarding on Arris router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, nginx

I am trying to host a website on my raspberry pi using nginx.  I am extremely confused about port forwarding or even which IP to use in my pi's configuration.

Right now, I can access my site through my local network only. I have namecheap.com redirecting requests for example.com to 192.168.0.10:8001. A ping from http://infobyip.com, however, says my IP is 123.124.125.126.  I don't even know where this number came from.

I can show ya'll any files you may need to see if someone could help out.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to superuser.com. As you can see, your question has been edited, as it is recommended to hide any identifiable details about your setup.

Comment: Might be a router issue.  http://superuser.com/questions/876383/trying-to-set-up-a-home-webserver-using-ubuntu-and-apache2/876390#876390

Answer (score 0):

Only your local network knows that your pi is on `192.168.0.10`, as that is a local IP. Your public IP, as seen from the rest of the world, is whatever your router gets from your ISP. You can check what this IP is by going to [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com). You then need to tell namecheap.com that your website is on the returned public IP (Which from now on, we'll assume is `162.225.119.254`), as that is your IP as seen from the point of view of the rest of the world. Then, since `162.225.119.254` is actually the IP of your router, you need to set up your router with port forwarding, so that your router forwards anything on port 8001 to your Raspberry Pis local IP (`192.168.0.10`).

**In short:**

1. Tell the rest of the world (via namecheap.com) that the domain
   should point to `162.225.119.254`
2. Tell your router to forward anything incoming on port 8001 to `192.168.0.10`

---

PS:

- Are you sure you want port 8001 and not port 80? The latter is the default. Otherwise you'd have to tell everyone that your website is on port 8001 instead. Unless ofcourse, you set up the port forwarding such that anything incoming on port 80 is forwarded to `192.168.0.10:8001`
- I do not know about namecheaps DNS system, but usually one would not specify the port for the webserver. If it still doesn't work at this point, omit any port definitions there, and try going by defaults instead. That means 8001 if that's what you've set nginx to listen to.
- Have you checked that your ISP has given you a static, or semi-static IP? It is common for private households to have dynamic IPs, meaning that your public IP changes every so often. If this is the case, you need to use a dynamic DNS service, such as [no-ip.com](http://no-ip.com)
- It usually takes some time for changes in DNS settings to propagate if cached somewhere. I just checked, and the domain you specified resolves to a public IP matching one that is close to the IP you didn't know the source of.

Comment: THANK THE LORDT! I don't exactly know how, but I finally got port 80 unblocked, which solved my problem. I now have namecheap pointing to the correct IP. Thank You!