# How can I see a website running on Apache installed on my PC from another device connected to the same ADSL router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, apache-http-server, intranet

I am not so into networking and I have the following problem.

On my Ubuntu system I have installed Apache web server on which run some web sites.

So now to access to these web site I need to open an URL like this into my browser:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite
```

The problem is that I want to test this website also on my smartphone (I have to check if it is correctly responsive), so the previous URL is not good !!!

My computer is connected to Internet by a standard ADSL router. Can I obtain the URL of my PC in some way and so connect to it by my smartphone?

Comment: This sounds like a similar problem:  http://superuser.com/questions/876383/trying-to-set-up-a-home-webserver-using-ubuntu-and-apache2/876390#876390

Comment: google "what is my ip" to get your ip.